# Apache ServiceMix 5.4.0 audit.log

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I have an installation of smx 5.4.0 that logs like crazy to the location {karaf.home}/data/security/audit.log. It contains lines: authentication attempted/autentication succeeded - smx. Probably karaf jaas module is responsible for this behavior: [karaf-jaas-module.xml](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.karaf.jaas/org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules/2.4.0/OSGI-INF/blueprint/karaf-jaas-module.xml)

Any ideas how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
karaf@root> config:edit org.apache.karaf.jaas 
karaf@root> config:propset audit.file.enabled false
karaf@root> config:update
```